# tsql query- consuming large space in tempdb

Tags: sql-server

How to find which query is consuming more space in temp db in SQL 2000 version. I do not want to use SQL profiler as there is not much space on disk.

Issue is its 2000 version. No information can be pulled using dmv's.

How to track that between 1-2 which query and on which database is making tempdb size to grow as much that notifications are coming that could allocate page under tempdb, it is full.

Comment: can you copy the database to a testing environment which has sufficient space and run the profiler there? also, why do you not want to use the sql server profiler?

Comment: No that can not be done as there are many databases and no test server in the environment

Comment: aNy other possible thing that can be done. what is sqltext??

Comment: is there any query that i can schedule to check which all transactions are running between 1-2

Comment: you could use the method described here to have the profiler write to a different drive which has sufficient space http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/08/21/sql-server-proilfer-and-the-c-drive-space-issue/

Comment: No profiler i can't use it takes space and load on server

Comment: Have you checked master..sysprocesses?  This table provides you with info, much like sys.sysprocesses, which includes the sql_handle to view text using fn_get_sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proc out of the script below which can be executed by a job.  More or less this is a template and can be altered however you see fit.

EDIT: Added additional comments below.

```
--Create temp table for sysprocesses records
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#SYSPROC') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SYSPROC;
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #SYSPROC
    (
        spid smallint NOT NULL,
        dbid smallint NOT NULL,
        blocked smallint NOT NULL,
        lastwaittype nchar(32) NOT NULL,
        cpu int NOT NULL,
        physical_io int NOT NULL,
        memusage int NOT NULL,
        login_time datetime NOT NULL,
        Last_batch datetime NOT NULL,
        status nchar(30) NOT NULL,
        cmd nchar(16) NOT NULL,
        loginame nchar(128) NOT NULL,
        sql_handle binary(20) NOT NULL,
        sh_text text NULL,
        snapshot_dt datetime NULL
    )
END;


--Insert sysprocesses records into temp #SYSPROC
INSERT INTO #SYSPROC
(
    spid,
    dbid,
    blocked,
    lastwaittype,
    cpu,
    physical_io,
    memusage,
    login_time,
    Last_batch,
    status,
    cmd,
    loginame,
    sql_handle,
    snapshot_dt
)
SELECT 
    sp.spid,
    sp.dbid,
    sp.blocked,
    sp.lastwaittype,
    sp.cpu,
    sp.physical_io,
    sp.memusage,
    sp.login_time,
    sp.Last_batch,
    sp.status,
    sp.cmd,
    sp.loginame,
    sp.sql_handle,
    GETDATE()
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses sp
WHERE sp.spid > 50;


/*
Update temp #SYSPROC with sql text.  Since CROSS APPLY is not
available in SQL Server 2000, a loop is required to interate
through each record.
*/
DECLARE @min_spid smallint = (SELECT MIN(spid) FROM #SYSPROC);
DECLARE @max_spid smallint = (SELECT MAX(spid) FROM #SYSPROC);
DECLARE @sql_handle binary(20);
DECLARE @sql_text varchar(max);

WHILE @min_spid <= @max_spid
BEGIN

    --Set @sql_handle variable to be evaluated by the fn_get_sql function
    SELECT 
        @sql_handle = S.sql_handle
    FROM #SYSPROC S
    WHERE spid = @min_spid

    --Identify the sql_text for the session by passing the @sql_handle variablet through fn_get_sql
    SELECT 
        @sql_text = H.text
    FROM fn_get_sql(@sql_handle) H

    --Update #SYSPROC with the sql_text.
    UPDATE S
    SET sh_text = @sql_text
    FROM #SYSPROC S
    WHERE spid = @min_spid

    SET @min_spid = @min_spid + 1

END;


INSERT INTO <SOMETABLE YOU CREATE>
(
    spid,
    dbid,
    blocked,
    lastwaittype,
    cpu,
    physical_io,
    memusage,
    login_time,
    Last_batch,
    status,
    cmd,
    loginame,
    sql_handle,
    snapshot_dt
)
SELECT 
    spid,
    dbid,
    blocked,
    lastwaittype,
    cpu,
    physical_io,
    memusage,
    login_time,
    Last_batch,
    status,
    cmd,
    loginame,
    sql_handle,
    snapshot_dt
FROM #SYSPROC
```

Hope this helps!